# Using dplyr to create new dataframe depending on thresholds

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

```
   Groups Names COL1  COL2  COL3        COL4
1      G1   SP1    1 0.400 0.500   Sequence1
2      G1   SP1    1 0.004 0.005   Sequence2
3      G1   SP1    0 0.004 0.005   Sequence3
4      G1   SP2    0 0.400 0.005 Sequence123
5      G1   SP2    0 0.004 0.500  Sequence14
6      G1   SP3    0 0.005 0.006  Sequence15
7      G1   SP5    1 0.400 0.006  Sequence16
8      G1   SP6    1 0.008 0.002  Sequence20
10     G2   Sp1    0 0.004 0.005  Sequence17
11     G2   SP1    0 0.050 0.600  Sequence18
12     G2   SP1    0 0.400 0.600   Sequence3
13     G2   SP2    0 0.004 0.005  Sequence22
14     G2   SP2    0 0.004 0.005  Sequence23
15     G2   SP5    0 0.004 0.005  Sequence16
16     G2   SP6    0 0.003 0.002  Sequence21
17     G2   SP7    0 0.560 0.760  Sequence67
```

Here is the `dput`:

```
dput(test_df)
structure(list(Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("G1", "G2"), class = "factor"), 
    Names = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("Sp1", "SP1", "SP2", 
    "SP3", "SP5", "SP6", "SP7"), class = "factor"), COL1 = c(1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), COL2 = c(0.4, 0.004, 0.004, 0.4, 0.004, 0.005, 0.4, 0.008, 
    0.004, 0.05, 0.4, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.003, 0.56), COL3 = c(0.5, 
    0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.5, 0.006, 0.006, 0.002, 0.005, 0.6, 
    0.6, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.002, 0.76), COL4 = structure(c(1L, 
    8L, 13L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 13L, 11L, 12L, 5L, 10L, 
    14L), .Label = c("Sequence1", "Sequence123", "Sequence14", 
    "Sequence15", "Sequence16", "Sequence17", "Sequence18", "Sequence2", 
    "Sequence20", "Sequence21", "Sequence22", "Sequence23", "Sequence3", 
    "Sequence67"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17"))
and from this dataf
```

rame I whant to get another dataframe such as :

```
    G1  G2
SP1 A   B
SP2 x   x
SP3 x   NA
SP4 NA  NA
SP5 A   X
SP6 a x
SP7 NA b
```

The idea is for each Groups to add the Names that are present in the row and add letters A,B, X or NA in the cells and the upper or lowercases will depend if we find an identic COL4 value for at least one species in anotger Groups.

- A is put when `any` row for the `Name` have a `COL1 >0` AND there is at least one Names that have the same `COL4` content as the same Name in a different Groups
- a is put when `any` row for the `Name` have a `COL1 >0` AND there is no Names that have the same `COL4` content as the same Name in a different Groups
- B is put when `any` row for the `Name` have a `COL1=0` AND `COL2` `AND` `COL3 > 0.05` AND there is at least one Names that have the same `COL4` content as the same Name in a different Groups
- b is put when `any` row for the `Name` have a `COL1=0` AND `COL2` `AND` `COL3 > 0.05` AND there is no Names that have the same `COL4` content as the same Name in a different Groups
- X is put when `all` row for the `Name` have a `COL1=0` AND ``` COL2``OR ``` `COL3 > 0.05`  `AND` there is at least one Names that have the same `COL4` content as the same Name in a different Groups
- x is put when `all` row for the `Name` have a `COL1=0` AND `COL2` `OR` `COL3 > 0.05` `AND` there is no Names that have the same `COL4` content as the same Name in a different Groups
- NA is put when there is not the `Name` in the `Group`

let's take 4 examples :

1)
We see for the `G1-SP1` that the `row1` has a `COL1  > 0`, then it will have a letter `A` or `a` in the new dataframe. 
Now in order to know if it will be an `A` or an `a` we have to look at the `COL4`, we see in the `row12` the  `Sequence3` is also present in the `G2` for the `SP1`, so it will be an 'A'

2) 
We see for the `G2-SP1` that the `row12` has a `COL2` and `COL3` are `> 0.05`, then it will have a letter `B` or `b` in the new dataframe.
And it will be `B` because in the `G1`, `row3` the `Sequence3` is also present in the G2 for the SP1.

3) 
We see for the `G2-SP2` that none row has a `COL1 >0X` or `COL2` and `COL3` are `> 0.05`, then it will have a letter `B` or `x` in the new dataframe.
And it will be `x` because none other `SP2` in other `Groups` have the same Sequence `(Sequence22,Sequence23 or Sequence24)

4)
We see for the `G1-SP6` the `row8` has a `COL1  > 0`, then it will have a letter `A` or `a` in the new dataframe. 
And it will be `a` because none other `SP1` in other `Groups` have the same Sequence `(Sequence20)`

`

For that I tried:

```
Env_table<-as.data.frame(test_df) %>%
  group_by(Groups,Names) %>%
  mutate(Env_variable = replace_na(COL1, "."),
         Env_variable = ifelse(any(COL1 >=1) , "A", Env_variable)) %>%
  mutate(Env_variable = ifelse(all(COL1 ==0 ) && all(COL2 >0.05) && all(COL3 >0.05) , "B", Env_variable)) %>%
  mutate(Env_variable = ifelse(all(COL1 ==0 ) && all(COL2 <0.05) && all(COL3 <0.05) , "X", Env_variable)) %>%
  mutate(Env_variable = ifelse(all(COL1 ==0 ) && all(COL2 <0.05) && all(COL3 >0.05) , "X", Env_variable)) %>%
  mutate(Env_variable = ifelse(all(COL1 ==0 ) && all(COL2 >0.05) && all(COL3 <0.05) , "X", Env_variable)) %>%
  mutate(Env_variable = ifelse(all(COL1 ==0) && all(!is.na(COL1)) && all(COL2 >0.05) && all(COL3 >0.05) , "*", Env_variable))%>%
  slice(1) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_col = Names, names_from = Groups, values_from = Env_variable) %>%
  arrange(as.integer(str_extract(Names, "\\d+")))
```

where `Env_variable` is juste an empty column that will store the A,B,X or NA values.

Thanks fo your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not crystal-clear, but here is an attempt to answer:

```
test_df %>% 
  group_by(Groups, Names) %>% 
  summarise(
    x=case_when(
      any(COL1>=1, na.rm=TRUE) ~ "A",
      any(COL1==0 & (COL2>0.05 & COL3>0.05), na.rm=TRUE) ~ "B",
      any(COL1==0 & (COL2<0.05 | COL3<0.05), na.rm=TRUE) ~ "X",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Groups, values_from = x)
```

This would give this output:

> ```
>   Names G1    G2   
>   <fct> <chr> <chr>
> 1 SP1   A     B    
> 2 SP2   X     X    
> 3 SP3   X     NA   
> 4 SP5   A     X    
> 5 SP6   A     X    
> 6 SP1   NA    X    
> 7 SP7   NA    B
> ```

Comment: @Grendel I would think my answer is covering your algorithm, but your expected answer is different. Why is G2-SP1 supposed to be B, since COL1==1 on row 9? Also, your algorithm is not clear enough on the difference between B and X. Note that "but" is not a logical term ;-)

Comment: Ho sorry I changed it. In fact it is X when the COL1=0 AND COL2 or COL3 are <0.05. The only way to have a B is to have COL1=0 AND COL2>0.05 AND COL3 > 0.05, the only way to have a A is to have COL1>1.

Comment: No you were right it was supposed to be A I changed it as well. Thank you for your time !

Comment: I edited a little bit the post in order to add more complexity (the idea is also to add upper or lowercases informations (that will depend if we find the same COL4 value for at least one species in another Groups). Maybe you have an idea in order to include that in your code ?

Comment: This is a different question that has little to do with your first one, it should be in another post. I should think about it but for now I'm not sure how you could do this.

Comment: Ok I'l create a new one