# Create a new dataframe using dplyr and some conditions in columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Hello here is a dataframe

```
   Groups Names COL1  COL2  COL3        COL4
1      G1   SP1    1 0.400 0.500   Sequence1
2      G1   SP1    1 0.004 0.005   Sequence2
3      G1   SP1    0 0.004 0.005   Sequence3
4      G1   SP2    0 0.400 0.005 Sequence123
5      G1   SP2    0 0.004 0.500  Sequence14
6      G1   SP3    0 0.005 0.006  Sequence15
7      G1   SP5    1 0.400 0.006  Sequence16
8      G1   SP6    1 0.008 0.002  Sequence20
10     G2   Sp1    0 0.004 0.005  Sequence17
11     G2   SP1    0 0.050 0.600  Sequence18
12     G2   SP1    0 0.400 0.600   Sequence3
13     G2   SP2    0 0.004 0.005  Sequence22
14     G2   SP2    0 0.004 0.005  Sequence23
15     G2   SP5    0 0.004 0.005  Sequence16
16     G2   SP6    0 0.003 0.002  Sequence21
17     G2   SP7    0 0.560 0.760  Sequence67
```

Here is the `dput`:

```
dput(test_df)
structure(list(Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("G1", "G2"), class = "factor"), 
    Names = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("Sp1", "SP1", "SP2", 
    "SP3", "SP5", "SP6", "SP7"), class = "factor"), COL1 = c(1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), COL2 = c(0.4, 0.004, 0.004, 0.4, 0.004, 0.005, 0.4, 0.008, 
    0.004, 0.05, 0.4, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.003, 0.56), COL3 = c(0.5, 
    0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.5, 0.006, 0.006, 0.002, 0.005, 0.6, 
    0.6, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.002, 0.76), COL4 = structure(c(1L, 
    8L, 13L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 13L, 11L, 12L, 5L, 10L, 
    14L), .Label = c("Sequence1", "Sequence123", "Sequence14", 
    "Sequence15", "Sequence16", "Sequence17", "Sequence18", "Sequence2", 
    "Sequence20", "Sequence21", "Sequence22", "Sequence23", "Sequence3", 
    "Sequence67"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17"))
```

and from this dataframe I want to get another dataframe such as :

```
    G1  G2
SP1 A   B
SP2 x   x
SP3 x   NA
SP4 NA  NA
SP5 A   X
SP6 a x
SP7 NA b
```

The idea is for each Groups to add the Names that are present in the row and add letters A,B, X or NA in the cells and the upper or lowercases will depend if we find an identic COL4 value for at least one species in anotger Groups.

- A is put when `any` row for the `Name` have a `COL1 >0` AND there is at least one Names that have the same `COL4` content as the same Name in a different Groups
- a is put when `any` row for the `Name` have a `COL1 >0` AND there is no Names that have the same `COL4` content as the same Name in a different Groups
- B is put when `any` row for the `Name` have a `COL1=0` AND `COL2` `AND` `COL3 > 0.05` AND there is at least one Names that have the same `COL4` content as the same Name in a different Groups
- b is put when `any` row for the `Name` have a `COL1=0` AND `COL2` `AND` `COL3 > 0.05` AND there is no Names that have the same `COL4` content as the same Name in a different Groups
- X is put when `all` row for the `Name` have a `COL1=0` AND ``` COL2``OR ``` `COL3 > 0.05`  `AND` there is at least one Names that have the same `COL4` content as the same Name in a different Groups
- x is put when `all` row for the `Name` have a `COL1=0` AND `COL2` `OR` `COL3 > 0.05` `AND` there is no Names that have the same `COL4` content as the same Name in a different Groups
- NA is put when there is not the `Name` in the `Group`

let's take 4 examples :

1)
We see for the `G1-SP1` that the `row1` has a `COL1  > 0`, then it will have a letter `A` or `a` in the new dataframe. 
Now in order to know if it will be an `A` or an `a` we have to look at the `COL4`, we see in the `row12` the  `Sequence3` is also present in the `G2` for the `SP1`, so it will be an 'A'

2) 
We see for the `G2-SP1` that the `row12` has a `COL2` and `COL3` are `> 0.05`, then it will have a letter `B` or `b` in the new dataframe.
And it will be `B` because in the `G1`, `row3` the `Sequence3` is also present in the G2 for the SP1.

3) 
We see for the `G2-SP2` that none row has a `COL1 >0X` or `COL2` and `COL3` are `> 0.05`, then it will have a letter `B` or `x` in the new dataframe.
And it will be `x` because none other `SP2` in other `Groups` have the same Sequence `(Sequence22,Sequence23 or Sequence24)

4)
We see for the `G1-SP6` the `row8` has a `COL1  > 0`, then it will have a letter `A` or `a` in the new dataframe. 
And it will be `a` because none other `SP1` in other `Groups` have the same Sequence `(Sequence20)`

`

thanks to Dan Chaltiel here : [Using dplyr to create new dataframe depending on thresholds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61595711/using-dplyr-to-create-new-dataframe-depending-on-thresholds#61598935) I got thise code that does not include the lower/upper case variables:

```
test_df %>% 
  group_by(Groups, Names) %>% 
  summarise(
    x=case_when(
      any(COL1>=1, na.rm=TRUE) ~ "A",
      any(COL1==0 & (COL2>0.05 & COL3>0.05), na.rm=TRUE) ~ "B",
      any(COL1==0 & (COL2<0.05 | COL3<0.05), na.rm=TRUE) ~ "X",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Groups, values_from = x)
```

with this code I was able to get then :

```
    G1  G2
SP1 A   B
SP2 X   X
SP3 X   NA
SP4 NA  NA
SP5 A   X
SP6 A X
SP7 NA B
```

Comment: It was in order to inspirate people

Comment: Ho I misunderstood, yes of course I added the right code sorry